# How to gray out a readonly checkbox

Tags: css, wordpress

I have the following HTML Structure. I try to gray out the checkbox when readonly="readonly" is valid. Is there a good way to do that via CSS?

```
<input type="email" class="input-text " name="billing_email" id="billing_email" placeholder="" value="1234@testmail.com" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="email username">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `disabled` attribute instead of `readonly`, it sounds like it will do what you want.

[See this code fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2v0zdyh4/)

Answer (score 1):

you can try input[readonly] {
color: gray
}

```css
input[readonly] {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" class="input-text " name="billing_email" id="billing_email" placeholder="" value="1234@testmail.com" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="email username">
```